# Panel Transition Matrix on Python

Tags: python, pandas, data-science, transition

I have a dataframe of panel data of companies ranked into deciles based on a variable X over time.

As an example, say we're only looking at 2 quarters, Q1 and Q2.

Firms are ranked into decile_1, decile_2, ... , decile_10 in Q1 and Q2.

I'm trying to get a 10x10 'transition matrix' which shows what % of firms moved (or didn't move) from one decile to another between Q1 and Q2.

Note that the actual problem is over multiple time periods, but I thought I'd reduce it to just 2 time periods to understand how it works before then 'scaling' to multiple periods.

Any ideas / help would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

This is a bit sloppy and can almost certainly be optimised, but it might be enough to get the ball rolling. This currently assumes only two time periods as it wasn't clear how you wanted to expand to multiple ones (i.e. should it be a multidimensional matrix?)

Lets say you have data that looks like this in a CSV, which doesn't seem an unreasonable format but even if it's not what you have shouldn't be too hard to get it into this.

```
| company | decile | Q |
+---------+--------+---+
| A       |      1 | 1 |
| B       |      2 | 1 |
| C       |      3 | 1 |
| A       |      2 | 2 |
| B       |      1 | 2 |
| C       |      3 | 2 |
| D       |      1 | 1 |
| D       |      1 | 2 |
+---------+--------+---+
```

The following code works by first sorting by the time period Q so we know we can just take the first row we get for a company as the Q1 one and vice versa for Q2. You can find out which ones were changed between the two periods by dropping the duplicates and then proceeding to record what the actual transitions were.

```py
import pandas as pd 
import numpy as np
df = pd.read_csv('example.csv').sort_values(by='Q')
n_c = len(set(df['decile']))
moved = df[['company','decile']].drop_duplicates(keep=False)

transitions = np.zeros((n_c,n_c))

for c, sdf in moved.groupby('company'):
    Q1,Q2 = sdf['decile'].values
    transitions[Q1-1][Q2-1]+=1

print(transitions)
```

In the multidimensional/multi period case you might need to do a lookup back on the original table to get exactly what the transitions through all the periods were and then loop over that in an inner loop.

This outputs

```
[[0. 1. 0.]
 [1. 0. 0.]   
 [0. 0. 0.]
```

as expected

Comment: Is there any Python package out there that creates the transition matrix for a number of varying scenarios?